# Using polymorphism to display output of a arraylist

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I need to display the first and last names of all contact entered when user selected Display contacts from the menu.  I also need to display all details of the contacts when the user inputs the Contact ID entered into the `ArrayList`. 
All I can get to display is the last contact entered. Am I not keeping the ArrayList once I go through once then go back to the menu and enter another contact? Or am I just not calling the print function right still to print all contacts in the arraylist.

If I enter 3 now it just goes back to the first line of the array and wants me to enter a contact ID, and goes through creating a contact again, not displaying what is already there.

```
package ooo1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactList {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int type = 0;

    while(type != 4){
      System.out.println("Please select an option:");
      System.out.println("Personal Contact: Enter 1");
      System.out.println("Business Contact: Enter 2");
      System.out.println("Display Contacts List: Enter 3");
      System.out.println("4 to quit");

      type = input1.nextInt();

      if(type == 4){
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        break;
      }

      ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter ContactId : ");
      String contactId = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter First Name : ");
      String firstName = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter Last Name : ");
      String lastName = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter Address : ");
      String address = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter Phone Number : ");
      String phoneNumber = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter Email Address : ");
      String emailAddress = input.nextLine();

      if(type == 1){
        System.out.println("Please enter Birthday: ");
        String dateofBirth = input.nextLine();
        Contact pcontact = new PersonalContact(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress, dateofBirth);
        contacts.add(pcontact);

        for (Contact showcontact: contacts){
          System.out.println(showcontact.displayContact());
        }
      }

      else if(type == 2){
        System.out.println("Please enter Job Title: ");
        String jobTitle = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Organization: ");
        String organization = input.nextLine();
        Contact bcontact = new BusinessContact(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress, jobTitle, organization);
        contacts.add(bcontact);

        for (Contact showcontact: contacts){
           System.out.println(showcontact.displayContact());
        }
      }

      else if(type ==3){
        for (Contact listcontacts: contacts){
            System.out.println(listcontacts.displayFullName());
        }
      }          
    }  
  }
}
```

Parent Class:

```
package ooo1;

public abstract class Contact {

  String contactId;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String address;
  String phoneNumber;
  String emailAddress;

  public Contact(String contactId,String firstName,String lastName, String address, String phoneNumber, String emailAddress)
  {
      this.contactId = contactId;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.address = address;
      this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
      this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
  }

  public void setContactId(String input){ this.contactId = input; }
  public String getContactId(){ return this.contactId; }
  public void setFirstName(String input){ this.firstName = input; }
  public String getFirstName(){ return this.firstName; }
  public void setLastName(String input){ this.lastName = input; }
  public String getLastName(){ return this.lastName; }
  public void setAddress(String input){ this.address = input; }
  public String getAddress(){ return this.address; }
  public void setPhoneNumber(String input){ this.phoneNumber = input; }
  public String getPhoneNumber(){ return this.phoneNumber; }
  public void setEmailAddress(String input){ this.emailAddress = input; }
  public String getEmailAddress(){ return this.emailAddress; }

  public String displayFullName(){
      System.out.println("Contact List:");
      return ("First Name:" + this.getFirstName() + "Last Name:" + this.getLastName());
  }

  public String displayContact(){
      return ("ContactID:" + this.getContactId() + "First Name:" + this.getFirstName() + "Last Name:" + this.getLastName() + "Address:" + this.getAddress() + "Phone Number:" + this.getPhoneNumber() + "Email Address" + this.getEmailAddress());
  }
}
```

One of the subclasses:  Other same just adds more variables:

```
package ooo1;

public class PersonalContact extends Contact {

  private String dateofBirth;

  public PersonalContact(String contactId, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phoneNumber, String emailAddress, String dateofBirth){      
      super(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress);    
      this.dateofBirth = dateofBirth;
  }

  public void setDateofBirth(String input){ this.dateofBirth=input; }

  public String getDateofBirth(){ return this.dateofBirth; }

  @Override
  public String displayContact(){
      System.out.println("Personal Contacts:");
      return super.displayContact() + "Date of Birth: " + this.getDateofBirth();   
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read up on how to create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org). There's no way all this code is needed here so please try to create a short example instead so people won't have to read through all irrelevant code.

Comment: Sorry, I am as new to posting as I am to programming. I don't know what part the code if relevant or irrelevant to my issue. Not sure that I have the displayContacts right anywhere in the class to even be able to call it correctly from main. When I try to add in another else statement to call the method from the Personal class it tells me:  non-static method displayContact() can not be referenced from a static content.  This is what I am putting at the end of main  if else(type == 3);
            PersonalContact.displayContacts();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a small example on how to use polymorphism, it's basically your classes stripped down to a bar minimum (this is what the SSCCE is about - stripping what's not relevant, like comments and multiple attributes that behaves the same etcetera).

When you call the displayContact() method in the on the Contact objects stored in the ArrayList polymorphism makes sure the correct displayContact method is used.

The reason `PersonalContact.displayContacts();` won't work is that you need to call the method on on object as it's not a static method.

I hope this example helps:

// Contact.java

```
public abstract class Contact {

    private final String name;

    public Contact(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String displayContact() {
         return "Contact name: " 
                + name + ". Contact type: " 
                + this.getClass().getName() + ". ";
    }
}
```

// PersonalContact.java

```
public class PersonalContact extends Contact {

    private final String dateofBirth;

    public PersonalContact(String name, String dateOfBirth) {
        super(name);
        this.dateofBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    @Override
    public String displayContact() {
        return super.displayContact() + "Date of birth: " + dateofBirth + ".";
    }
}
```

// BusinessContact.java

```
public class BusinessContact extends Contact {

    private final String organization;

    public BusinessContact(String name, String org) {
        super(name);
        this.organization = org;
    }

    @Override
    public String displayContact() {
        return super.displayContact() + "Organization: " + organization + ".";
    }
}
```

// ContactList.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        PersonalContact personalContact1 = new PersonalContact("John", "1980-01-01");
        BusinessContact businessContact1 = new BusinessContact("theCompany", "The Company");

        contacts.add(personalContact1);
        contacts.add(businessContact1);

        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            System.out.println(contact.displayContact());
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT added some more referencing issues mentioned in a comment.**

The reason you can't print out anything is that the block of code asking for input is always executed as it's not contained in the `type 1 or 2` blocks. To remedy that I'd suggest the following changes:

First, move the ArrayList and Scanner to the start of the main method:

```
ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then enclose the entire block of code dealing with input in an `if` block so it looks like this:

```
if(type==1 || type==2){

        Contact contact = null;

        System.out.println("Please enter ContactId : ");
        String contactId = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter First Name : ");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Last Name : ");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Address : ");
        String address = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Phone Number : ");
        String phoneNumber = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Email Address : ");
        String emailAddress = input.nextLine();

        if(type == 1){
          System.out.println("Please enter Birthday: ");
          String dateofBirth = input.nextLine();
          contact = new PersonalContact(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress, dateofBirth);
        }

        else if(type == 2){

          System.out.println("Please enter Job Title: ");
          String jobTitle = input.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Please enter Organization: ");
          String organization = input.nextLine();
          contact = new BusinessContact(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress, jobTitle, organization);
        }

        // add the new contact
        contacts.add(contact);
        // print out the newly created contact here
        System.out.println(contact.displayContact());
    }
```

Also, you don't really need two Scanner-objects, just reuse one of them :)

And you should consider moving the `if(type==4)` to after the other blocks so that it comes in order (that's just a matter of style though).

Comment: Well that took me awhile to get but got it to print out the contact details for the last entry added to the array, but still can't figure out how to get it to print all the contact listed in the array by the method in display full name, or with displaycontact. All I get is the last contact entered.  Am I not keeping what is entered when I go back through the loop again to enter a new or different contact?    Changes I made shown above.

Comment: @user3196742 I'll edit my answer and append something relevant to your issues.

Comment: Did that and now it skips the input for add ContactID print the line but doesn't wait for any input. Bigger issue though it the output is still just the last contact I entered. Still not getting it to print out any contact I have entered. I feel like I am missing a important part here and don't know enough to figure out what it is. I need it to print out a whole list of contact entered. Am I missing something when I go back to menu to enter a new contact into the array. It acts like it is only seeing the last one entered.

Comment: I figured this out, you pointed me in the right direction the first time just didn't realize it till now. Also got the input fixed.

Comment: @user3196742 Happy to have helped :) The reason ContactID was skipped is that the nextInt() call leaves the newline which then gets consumed by the next nextInt() call. Put a next() call after the first nextInt call.